# Can't compile a vscode extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I started a new vscode extension with

`npm install -g yo generator-code`

`yo code`

but when I try to compile it I get

```
> custom-scripts@0.0.1 compile
> tsc -p ./

../node_modules/@types/imagemin-mozjpeg/index.d.ts:1:24 - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("imagemin")' call instead.

1 import { Plugin } from "imagemin";
                         ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/imagemin-optipng/index.d.ts:1:24 - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("imagemin")' call instead.

1 import { Plugin } from "imagemin";
                         ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/imagemin-svgo/index.d.ts:7:24 - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("imagemin")' call instead.

7 import { Plugin } from 'imagemin';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/imagemin-gifsicle/index.d.ts:1:24 - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will 
produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("imagemin")' call instead.

1 import { Plugin } from "imagemin";
                         ~~~~~~~~~~


Found 4 errors in 4 files.

Errors  Files
     1  ../node_modules/@types/imagemin-mozjpeg/index.d.ts:1
     1  ../node_modules/@types/imagemin-optipng/index.d.ts:1
     1  ../node_modules/@types/imagemin-svgo/index.d.ts:7
     1  node_modules/@types/imagemin-gifsicle/index.d.ts:1
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "custom-scripts",
  "displayName": "custom-scripts",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.84.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.replaceAsset",
    "onCommand:extension.replaceLocaleAsset"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "custom-scripts.asset",
        "title": "Replace link with blade asset code."
      },
      {
        "command": "custom-scripts.locale_asset",
        "title": "Replace link with blade locale_asset code."
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.84.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.0",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.6",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "glob": "^10.3.10",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

`npm -v && node -v`

- 10.2.4
- v21.2.0

BTW I realize the *Consider writing a dynamic 'import("imagemin")' call instead* but I want to avoid modifying node_modules files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format ESM (ECMAScript Module) is the common module type for all JS/TS modules. There are others, but they are quickly losing ground and CommonJS only works in Node.js. Unfortunately, also VS Code needs an extension to be a CommonJS module (hopefully they change that soon). That means, you need an extra step if you want to import ESM modules without dynamic imports: make your extension an ESM module, by setting the field `"type": "module"`. With this setting your project uses ESM as module type. And since ESM cannot be loaded in VS Code you have to use a bundler (which is a good idea anyway) and let it generate a CommonJS bundle file from the project files.

ESbuild is perfect for that and easy to use, comes with built-in TypeScript support and needs no explicit configuration by default. Add this NPM script to your package.json:

```
"build": "tsc -b && esbuild ./src/extension.ts --bundle --outfile=out/main.cjs --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node --sourcemap=external --loader:.svg=file",
```

Adjust source and target names to what you are using and off you go. This will create `out/main.cjs` which you can reference as your `main` file in package.json.

You have to add esbuild as dev dependency:

```
npm i -save-dev esbuild
```

for this to work.